# Определение типов d.ts в JavaScript модуле

Tags: javascript, typescript, pycharm

я пишу небольшую библиотеку обёртку над axios, на ванильном js. Она устанавливается как обычная библиотека через yarn или npm. Но при работе с классом импортированном из библиотеке, отсутвуют автодополнение. Я подумал что это может исправить добавление index.d.ts, подсмотрел это в модуле axios, но не могу сообразить как это сделать. Может у кого то есть советы?

Comment: флаг `--declaration` в конфиге тайпскрипта надо поставить. Но про эту тему погугли лучше. Он для каждого файла будет делать делать д.тс. Как-то можно можно это всё превратить в один. В `package.json` указывается это в поле [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html). Я помню, что для своей какой-то либы вручную потом склеивал. Но это не очень вариант :) Но начни изучение с этого.

Comment: Но я не использую typescript, есть ли возможность как то это написать руками? Я  давно прописывал `d.ts` файл для сторонней библиотеки, но там было все достаточно просто, нужно было указать для какой библиотеки я использую этот файл и указать его package.json, но тут я сам пытаюсь сделать либу, и что то как то не понимаю) @AlexSazonov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом я переписал все на тайп скрипт и сгенерировал d.ts, но в целом можно было обойтись без этого. Как минимум в package.json необходимо было указать параметр "types" который должен указывать на корневой "d.ts". Это одна из причин почему не заработали подсказки/hints когда описывал d.ts файл в ручную.